# Как мне отображать CardView, а потом сделать ее невидимой?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

У меня есть страничка с карточками и там CardView, которое нужно драгендропать наверх или свайпать вправо, при этом есть изначальный CardView, который нужно драгендропнуть наверх, после чего начнется тест. Как это можно реализовать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После свайпа первой CardView(скриншот 1) начинается тест и должно отобразиться второе CardView(скриншот 2).

Я написал код, но он не работает.

```
    inner class CardViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val rlayout1 = itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.crd_cards)
    private val textCrdCrimeantatar = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_crd_crimeantatar)
    private val textCrdRussian = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_crd_russian)
    fun bind(item: WordStudyCard) {
        rlayout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
        textCrdCrimeantatar.text = item.crimeantatar
        textCrdRussian.text = item.russian
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) callback.onItemClicked(items[adapterPosition])
        }
    }
}
```

Выдается ошибка: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: У вас обычный NPE. Проверьте разметку, что ID там правильные и сама разметка не перепутана. И/или покажите эту разметку.

Comment: И вправду) Спасибо, а я сидел ломал голову в чем проблема. Я оказывается id не указал для CardView. Я даже подумать не мог, что я на таком мог проколоться. Спасибо)